# Failed to load image Python extension

Tags: python, torchvision

Hello I am getting this error I tried different torch and torchvision versions and nothing worked. Any suggestion please?

```
env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: libtorch_cuda_cu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}")
```

I tried different torch and torchvision versions

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 7):

**Cause of problem**

The versions of Pytorch and Torchvision do not correspond to the following [link](https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/). According to your own situation, reload Torchvision and Pytorch.

**Problem solving**

1. Enter your Anaconda environment and pip list. Show all our libraries. You can see here. For me, the torch was 1.11.0. According to the above [link](https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/), the corresponding torchvision should be 0.12.0.
2. pip3 uninstall torchvision.
3. pip3 install torchvision==0.12.0. Specify the installation torchvision version of.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this error too, but on a Raspberry Pi 4. Mine didn't specify libcuda was missing, but after digging around some github issues, it appears the cause was another library, most likely `image.so` was missing. So the underlying reason for this is that the torchvision wheel was oddly built without some libraries. If you're like me, and working on any debian based aarch64, the workaround that worked for me was downgrading `torchvision` to 0.10.0. So this did the trick:

```
pip install torchvision==0.10.0
```